# Bootstrap 3 & Font-Awesome 4 colorchange

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome-4

how can i change the fa fa-xxxx from font-awesome the color from gray into white for my bootstrap3? The background ist black so i need an other color for the icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty behind using icon fonts is that once you've imported them into your site, you can change their size, colour or other properties as you would any other font. So for example:

**HTML**

```
<i class="fa fa-bullhorn"> </i> hello world
```

**CSS**

```
i.fa{
    font-size:100px;
    color:olive;
}
```

Hope this helps!

See this live: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/GLVSx/